# i need to get the name of a variable from a file

Tags: php

As the title said i need a way to set the variable name depending of what the name of the picture is (i got over 100 different pictures)

Since i got custom classes in another php file for each picture (like tags) like for example:

```
$picture1 = "hillside sunset";
$picture2 = "beach cyprus";
```

and so on, so i need to fetch each variable for each picture

Heres the current loop where the div class is going to be each pictures name ($PICTURENAME is just to define where this code goes and is irelevant codewise):

```
<?php
foreach (glob("img/*.jpg") as $filename)
{
$path = $filename;
$file = basename($path);
$file = basename($path, ".jpg");
echo '<a href="?image='.$file.'"><div class="'.$PICTURENAME.'" id="'.$file.'"><img src="'.$filename.'"> '.$file.' </div></a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use 100+ variables. Using a database would make far more sense, but if you don't want to get into learning that (you should, though), using a data structure would still make far more sense.

You could create *one* array (and use it as a map), and have the filename as the key, and the value would be the tags.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you can address a variable using another variable:

```
$name = "foo";
${$name} = "bar";

echo $foo; // prints "bar"
echo ${$name}; // the same as above
```

However, as Kitsune already recommended, you are better off using something else, e.g., an array.